# Why can't Eclipse push down static fields?

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

When I try to use an Eclipse automated push down refactoring on a static field, I get the error:

> "To activate this refactoring, please select the name of a non-binary instance method or field."

When I remove the static keyword, the refactoring can go forward. What does eclipse mean by "binary field," and why does this restriction exist?

Comment: AFAIK, *non-binary* means the same as *non-native*; i.e., it's pure Java, no JNI. Also, static fields, by definition, are not instance fields; they are class-level fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a static field/method only belong to the class, you cannot push down it to a subclass.

If `A` is a superclass of `B`, then for a static method in `A` called `a`, you can only use it as `A.a`, not as `B.a`. Pushing down this method will certainly change what the class is doing , and affect the meaning of the program.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand Eclipse's logic here. I actually was trying to change the behavior of the program by moving a bunch of fields from A to B. There are a lot of fields to move, so I thought I would save some time by doing a mass push-down rather than moving them one by one.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use Refactor -> move?